# maps of Karnaugh in LaTeX

Tags: karnaugh

How can I make a Karnaugh map of this type in LaTeX?
Thank you
[image]

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/drawing-karnaughs-maps-in-latex could help, or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87690/how-can-i-draw-a-karnaugh-map

Comment: or any of the other questions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karnaugh

Comment: Thanks, but I'm new to LaTex and I have not found a format that I grouped in the previous way.