# Can Somebody explain how I should use the implicants in the linked Karnaugh example?

Tags: karnaugh

[How to do a karnaugh map?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94443/how-to-do-a-karnaugh-map)

I don't understand the arguments and different functions of drawing the implicants.
Thanks a lot!

I want to know I have to draw the rectangles as shown as in the picture. I don't know how this is meant. Do I have to change the commands? The commands have some args, what do they mean? Can maybe somebody explain just the command 'implicant'? `\newcommand{\implicant}[3][0]{ \draw[rounded corners=3pt] ($(#2.north west)+(135:#1)$) rectangle ($(#3.south east)+(-45:#1)$); }` 
How I'm supposed to use it? For which rectangles and how I get it on the place where I want it?`

Timmy

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to clarify it. Are you using one of the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87690/how-can-i-draw-a-karnaugh-map)? What exactly do you need help understanding? Explaining everything is too much for an answer, I think, so you need to be a bit more specific about where you are getting stuck. If you post the code you've been trying, that would make it clearer. Or you could include the particular bit of code you want explained from the answer you are using.

Comment: Or are you asking about something [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/drawing-karnaughs-maps-in-latex)? I see you asked a question in the answer space there which got deleted.

Comment: I want to use a 4x4 karnaugh map. I don't know how I can mark the implicants (so select cubes of all 1 and don't cares e.g.). I see that there are some functions for it (implicant, implicantcostats,...  (3 or 4)), but I don't know for what I should use which function and how the args have to be. But I will read the link now and hope that it is what I searched for :)

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what any of that means. If you are trying to understand one of the answers in the links, I might be able to help. But I have no idea which functions you are trying to use since the answers use different solutions to draw similar things.