# setting values in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

To anyone who can help me:
I recently found this code posted as an answer to this ([Drawing Karnaugh's maps in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/drawing-karnaughs-maps-in-latex/140581#140581)) question on TeX exchange but I am having trouble adapting it to my needs.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

%isolated term
%#1- space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2- node
%#3- filling color
\newcommand{\implicantsol}[3][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#3, opacity=.3] ($(#2.north west)+(135:#1)$) rectangle ($(#2.south east)+(-45:#1)$);
    }


%internal group
%#1-space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2-top left node
%#3-bottom right node
%#4-filling color
\newcommand{\implicant}[4][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=.3] ($(#2.north west)+(135:#1)$) rectangle ($(#3.south east)+(-45:#1)$);
    }

%group lateral borders
%#1-space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2-top left node
%#3-bottom right node
%#4-filling color
\newcommand{\implicantcostats}[4][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=.3] ($(rf.east |- #2.north)+(90:#1)$)-| ($(#2.east)+(0:#1)$) |- ($(rf.east |- #3.south)+(-90:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=.3] ($(cf.west |- #2.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(#3.west)+(180:#1)$) |- ($(cf.west |- #3.south)+(-90:#1)$);
}

%group top-bottom borders
%#1-space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2-top left node
%#3-bottom right node
%#4-filling color
\newcommand{\implicantdaltbaix}[4][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=.3] ($(cf.south -| #2.west)+(180:#1)$) |- ($(#2.south)+(-90:#1)$) -| ($(cf.south -| #3.east)+(0:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=.3] ($(rf.north -| #2.west)+(180:#1)$) |- ($(#3.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(rf.north -| #3.east)+(0:#1)$);
}

%group corners
%#1-space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2-filling color
\newcommand{\implicantcantons}[2][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(rf.east |- 0.south)+(-90:#1)$) -| ($(0.east |- cf.south)+(0:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(rf.east |- 8.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(8.east |- rf.north)+(0:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(cf.west |- 2.south)+(-90:#1)$) -| ($(2.west |- cf.south)+(180:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(cf.west |- 10.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(10.west |- rf.north)+(180:#1)$);
}

%Empty Karnaugh map 4x4
\newenvironment{Karnaugh}%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=0.8]
\draw (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw (0,4) -- node [pos=0.7,above right,anchor=south west] {cd} node [pos=0.7,below left,anchor=north east] {ab} ++(135:1);
%
\matrix (mapa) [matrix of nodes,
        column sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        row sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        every node/.style={minimum size=0.3mm},
        anchor=8.center,
        ampersand replacement=\&] at (0.5,0.5)
{
                       \& |(c00)| 00         \& |(c01)| 01         \& |(c11)| 11         \& |(c10)| 10         \& |(cf)| \phantom{00} \\
|(r00)| 00             \& |(0)|  \phantom{0} \& |(1)|  \phantom{0} \& |(3)|  \phantom{0} \& |(2)|  \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(r01)| 01             \& |(4)|  \phantom{0} \& |(5)|  \phantom{0} \& |(7)|  \phantom{0} \& |(6)|  \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(r11)| 11             \& |(12)| \phantom{0} \& |(13)| \phantom{0} \& |(15)| \phantom{0} \& |(14)| \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(r10)| 10             \& |(8)|  \phantom{0} \& |(9)|  \phantom{0} \& |(11)| \phantom{0} \& |(10)| \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(rf) | \phantom{00}   \&                    \&                    \&                    \&                    \&                     \\
};
}%
{
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%Empty Karnaugh map 2x4
\newenvironment{Karnaughvuit}%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=0.8]
\draw (0,0) grid (4,2);
\draw (0,2) -- node [pos=0.7,above right,anchor=south west] {bc} node [pos=0.7,below left,anchor=north east] {a} ++(135:1);
%
\matrix (mapa) [matrix of nodes,
        column sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        row sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        every node/.style={minimum size=0.3mm},
        anchor=4.center,
        ampersand replacement=\&] at (0.5,0.5)
{
                      \& |(c00)| 00         \& |(c01)| 01         \& |(c11)| 11         \& |(c10)| 10         \& |(cf)| \phantom{00} \\
|(r00)| 0             \& |(0)|  \phantom{0} \& |(1)|  \phantom{0} \& |(3)|  \phantom{0} \& |(2)|  \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(r01)| 1             \& |(4)|  \phantom{0} \& |(5)|  \phantom{0} \& |(7)|  \phantom{0} \& |(6)|  \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(rf) | \phantom{00}  \&                    \&                    \&                    \&                    \&                     \\
};
}%
{
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%Empty Karnaugh map 2x2
\newenvironment{Karnaughquatre}%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=0.8]
\draw (0,0) grid (2,2);
\draw (0,2) -- node [pos=0.7,above right,anchor=south west] {b} node [pos=0.7,below left,anchor=north east] {a} ++(135:1);
%
\matrix (mapa) [matrix of nodes,
        column sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        row sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        every node/.style={minimum size=0.3mm},
        anchor=2.center,
        ampersand replacement=\&] at (0.5,0.5)
{
          \& |(c00)| 0          \& |(c01)| 1  \\
|(r00)| 0 \& |(0)|  \phantom{0} \& |(1)|  \phantom{0} \\
|(r01)| 1 \& |(2)|  \phantom{0} \& |(3)|  \phantom{0} \\
};
}%
{
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%Defines 8 or 16 values (0,1,X)
\newcommand{\contingut}[1]{%
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 0]  in {#1}
     \path (\xi) node {\x};
}

%Places 1 in listed positions
\newcommand{\minterms}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {1};
}

%Places 0 in listed positions
\newcommand{\maxterms}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {0};
}

%Places X in listed positions
\newcommand{\indeterminats}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {X};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Karnaugh}
        \contingut{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1}
       \implicant{0}{2}{red}
       \implicantdaltbaix[3pt]{3}{10}{blue}
       \implicantcostats{4}{14}{green}
    \end{Karnaugh}
    %
    \begin{Karnaughvuit}
       \minterms{3,4}
        \maxterms{0,1,6,7}
       \indeterminats{2,5}
       \implicant{3}{2}{green}
       \implicant{4}{5}{}
    \end{Karnaughvuit}
    %
    \begin{Karnaughquatre}
        \minterms{1,2}
       \maxterms{0,3}
       \implicantsol{1}{green}
       \implicantsol{2}{red}
    \end{Karnaughquatre}

\end{document}
```

What I would like to do is be able to set the "ab" and "cd" text in the same way that the elements of the array are from inside the document instead of the preamble. One issue that I encountered is that if I manually set the text to be something in a math environment like $x_0$ I get a "bad box" error. My question is in 2 parts: 1. is there a way to prevent this bad box error and allow me to set this text to be something from the math environment (even if its only x_i that would be enough) and 2. how would I make a command to set the text from inside the document instead of the preamble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nice to see that my code is useful. I've added two arguments to each `karnaugh` environment:

```
\begin{karnaugh}{ab}{cd}...\end{karnaugh}
\begin{karnaughvuit}{a}{bc}...\end{karnaughvuit}
\begin{karnaughquatre}{a}{c}...\end{karnaughquatre}
```

whatever you write in first argument will be placed as columns label while the second argument will be used as rows label.

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

%isolated term
%#1- space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2- node
%#3- filling color
\newcommand{\implicantsol}[3][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#3, opacity=.3] ($(#2.north west)+(135:#1)$) rectangle ($(#2.south east)+(-45:#1)$);
    }


%internal group
%#1-space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2-top left node
%#3-bottom right node
%#4-filling color
\newcommand{\implicant}[4][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=.3] ($(#2.north west)+(135:#1)$) rectangle ($(#3.south east)+(-45:#1)$);
    }

%group lateral borders
%#1-space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2-top left node
%#3-bottom right node
%#4-filling color
\newcommand{\implicantcostats}[4][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=.3] ($(rf.east |- #2.north)+(90:#1)$)-| ($(#2.east)+(0:#1)$) |- ($(rf.east |- #3.south)+(-90:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=.3] ($(cf.west |- #2.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(#3.west)+(180:#1)$) |- ($(cf.west |- #3.south)+(-90:#1)$);
}

%group top-bottom borders
%#1-space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2-top left node
%#3-bottom right node
%#4-filling color
\newcommand{\implicantdaltbaix}[4][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=.3] ($(cf.south -| #2.west)+(180:#1)$) |- ($(#2.south)+(-90:#1)$) -| ($(cf.south -| #3.east)+(0:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=.3] ($(rf.north -| #2.west)+(180:#1)$) |- ($(#3.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(rf.north -| #3.east)+(0:#1)$);
}

%group corners
%#1-space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2-filling color
\newcommand{\implicantcantons}[2][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(rf.east |- 0.south)+(-90:#1)$) -| ($(0.east |- cf.south)+(0:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(rf.east |- 8.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(8.east |- rf.north)+(0:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(cf.west |- 2.south)+(-90:#1)$) -| ($(2.west |- cf.south)+(180:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(cf.west |- 10.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(10.west |- rf.north)+(180:#1)$);
}

%Empty Karnaugh map 4x4
\newenvironment{Karnaugh}[2]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=0.8]
\draw (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw (0,4) -- node [pos=0.7,above right,anchor=south west] {#2} node [pos=0.7,below left,anchor=north east] {#1} ++(135:1);
%
\matrix (mapa) [matrix of nodes,
        column sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        row sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        every node/.style={minimum size=0.3mm},
        anchor=8.center,
        ampersand replacement=\&] at (0.5,0.5)
{
                       \& |(c00)| 00         \& |(c01)| 01         \& |(c11)| 11         \& |(c10)| 10         \& |(cf)| \phantom{00} \\
|(r00)| 00             \& |(0)|  \phantom{0} \& |(1)|  \phantom{0} \& |(3)|  \phantom{0} \& |(2)|  \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(r01)| 01             \& |(4)|  \phantom{0} \& |(5)|  \phantom{0} \& |(7)|  \phantom{0} \& |(6)|  \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(r11)| 11             \& |(12)| \phantom{0} \& |(13)| \phantom{0} \& |(15)| \phantom{0} \& |(14)| \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(r10)| 10             \& |(8)|  \phantom{0} \& |(9)|  \phantom{0} \& |(11)| \phantom{0} \& |(10)| \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(rf) | \phantom{00}   \&                    \&                    \&                    \&                    \&                     \\
};
}%
{
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%Empty Karnaugh map 2x4
\newenvironment{Karnaughvuit}[2]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=0.8]
\draw (0,0) grid (4,2);
\draw (0,2) -- node [pos=0.7,above right,anchor=south west] {#2} node [pos=0.7,below left,anchor=north east] {#1} ++(135:1);
%
\matrix (mapa) [matrix of nodes,
        column sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        row sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        every node/.style={minimum size=0.3mm},
        anchor=4.center,
        ampersand replacement=\&] at (0.5,0.5)
{
                      \& |(c00)| 00         \& |(c01)| 01         \& |(c11)| 11         \& |(c10)| 10         \& |(cf)| \phantom{00} \\
|(r00)| 0             \& |(0)|  \phantom{0} \& |(1)|  \phantom{0} \& |(3)|  \phantom{0} \& |(2)|  \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(r01)| 1             \& |(4)|  \phantom{0} \& |(5)|  \phantom{0} \& |(7)|  \phantom{0} \& |(6)|  \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(rf) | \phantom{00}  \&                    \&                    \&                    \&                    \&                     \\
};
}%
{
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%Empty Karnaugh map 2x2
\newenvironment{Karnaughquatre}[2]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=0.8]
\draw (0,0) grid (2,2);
\draw (0,2) -- node [pos=0.7,above right,anchor=south west] {#2} node [pos=0.7,below left,anchor=north east] {#1} ++(135:1);
%
\matrix (mapa) [matrix of nodes,
        column sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        row sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        every node/.style={minimum size=0.3mm},
        anchor=2.center,
        ampersand replacement=\&] at (0.5,0.5)
{
          \& |(c00)| 0          \& |(c01)| 1  \\
|(r00)| 0 \& |(0)|  \phantom{0} \& |(1)|  \phantom{0} \\
|(r01)| 1 \& |(2)|  \phantom{0} \& |(3)|  \phantom{0} \\
};
}%
{
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%Defines 8 or 16 values (0,1,X)
\newcommand{\contingut}[1]{%
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 0]  in {#1}
     \path (\xi) node {\x};
}

%Places 1 in listed positions
\newcommand{\minterms}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {1};
}

%Places 0 in listed positions
\newcommand{\maxterms}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {0};
}

%Places X in listed positions
\newcommand{\indeterminats}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {X};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Karnaugh}{$ab$}{$cd$}
        \contingut{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1}
       \implicant{0}{2}{red}
       \implicantdaltbaix[3pt]{3}{10}{blue}
       \implicantcostats{4}{14}{green}
    \end{Karnaugh}
    %
    \begin{Karnaughvuit}{c}{ab}
       \minterms{3,4}
        \maxterms{0,1,6,7}
       \indeterminats{2,5}
       \implicant{3}{2}{green}
       \implicant{4}{5}{}
    \end{Karnaughvuit}
    %
    \begin{Karnaughquatre}{x}{y}
        \minterms{1,2}
       \maxterms{0,3}
       \implicantsol{1}{green}
       \implicantsol{2}{red}
    \end{Karnaughquatre}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]