# Karnaugh map according to image included

Tags: tikz-pgf, karnaugh

How can I draw one of these Karnaugh maps using tixz? I would like to have q_x^+ in the corner.

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Answering is fun but typing all the data in your tables is not.

Comment: You can try addapting this code: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140581/1952

Comment: See also the questions on the right under 'Related'.