# Drawing Karnaugh Map - Modification in karnaugh-map package

Tags: tikz-pgf, karnaugh

I need to draw Karnaugh Map for a book.  package mentioned in this answer [Drawing Karnaugh's maps in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/drawing-karnaughs-maps-in-latex) is excellent.  I have two questions

1. How to turn colouring On.
2. Can we shift position of x,y,z as shown in the [alternate answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140581/1952)

.

```
\documentclass{memoir}    
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\begin{document}
    \begin{karnaugh-map}*[4][2][1][$yz$][$x$]
        \maxterms{0,2,3}
        \minterms{1,4,5,6,7}
        \autoterms[X]
        \implicant{4}{6}
        \implicant{1}{5}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. According to the documentation ([see here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/karnaugh-map/karnaugh-map.pdf)) removing the star at the start of the `karnaugh-map` environment is the right way. It should be `\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][$yz$][$x$]` then.
2. Without making changes to the source code of the package itself this does not seem to be possible as the positions for the labels are "hardcoded" ([source code](https://github.com/2pi/karnaugh-map/blob/5d347bf/karnaugh-map.dtx#L383)). If you comment out lines 250 to 268 inside `karnaugh-map.sty` you could play a little bit based on this code:

   ```
   \documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage{karnaugh-map}
   \begin{document}
       \begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][$yz$][$x$]
           \maxterms{0,2,3}
           \minterms{1,4,5,6,7}
           \autoterms[X]
           \implicant{4}{6}
           \implicant{1}{5}
           \node at (-0.25,2.5) {$yz$};           % row name
           \node at (-0.6,2.25) {$x$};            % column name
           \draw[ultra thin] (0,2) -- (-1,2.75);  % diagonal line
       \end{karnaugh-map}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: It is a bad habit to point to a file in `master` branch because the next commit may change your pointer (because `master` is moving). So the GitHub link should use the commit id (or the beginning of the commit id), like this [https://github.com/2pi/karnaugh-map/blob/5d347bf/karnaugh-map.dtx#L383](https://github.com/2pi/karnaugh-map/blob/5d347bf/karnaugh-map.dtx#L383) for example.

Answer (score 5):

1. Coloring is turned off when adding an asterisk to the environment. See the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/karnaugh-map/karnaugh-map.pdf) for more information. Therefore remove the asterisk when you begin the `karnaugh-map` environment making your environment line;

   ```
   \begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][$yz$][$x$]
   ```
2. This is not directly supported by the package. Fortunately this could manually be done with *version v1.0* as suggested in the [answer by @epR8GaYuh](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343086/120806). It can even be done without modifying the package. If you supply an empty set of labels, they will "disappear" and you may add you own using `tikz`. Finally you could also add decorations if desired. Based on code from your linked [example by Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140581/1952) the following can be produced:

   ```
   \documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage{karnaugh-map}
   \begin{document}
     \begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][][] % note empty X and Y labels
       \maxterms{0,2,3}
       \minterms{1,4,5,6,7}
       \autoterms[X]
       \implicant{4}{6}
       \implicant{1}{5}
       % note: posistion for start of \draw is (0, Y) where Y is
       % the Y size(number of cells high) in this case Y=2
       \draw[color=black, ultra thin] (0, 2) --
       node [pos=0.7, above right, anchor=south west] {$yz$} % Y label
       node [pos=0.7, below left, anchor=north east] {$x$} % X label
       ++(135:1);
     \end{karnaugh-map}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: Example]
   This should work for all combinations of maps with one submap(`Z size = 1`) provided that `Y` is changed accordingly and could further be customized to work with multiple submaps if needed.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm the author of `karnaugh-map`</sub>

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX and thank you for `karnaugh-map`.

Comment: Thanks, and thank you for the inspiration and your related posts!

Comment: Thanks @Mattias for nice package and improved solution.  I did just same for passing Nil set of labels and then I used solution given by Ignasi.  Thanks to both.