# Change negation ordering of karnaughmap tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, karnaugh

I know there are already great Karnaugh-Questions out there but mine is specifically about reordering the Negations of a `karnaughmap`-Map.

I'm currently using the [`karnaughmap`](http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/karnaughmap/karnaughmap.pdf)-Package by Michael Vonbun but I am not bound to this package.
The package is quite easy to use and I was already able to *sort of* reproduce what i was looking to:

[image: image of hand drawn KV Diagram]
[image: image of TikZ KV Diagram]

This is my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{karnaughmap}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \karnaughmapcolorfield{4}{028a}{violet!50}

    \karnaughmap
    [omitidx,omitbinaries,
    omitnegated=false,
    variables={{x_0}{x_2}{x_1}{x_3}},
    function=y_0]
    {1010 0000 1010 0000}
    % i actually want to display 1111 0000 0000 0000
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

<sub>[view result on sharelatex.com](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58f7745012a600d06b958a63)</sub>

I am misusing the variable naming and the binary to get the counter-clockwise naming. I was ok with this until i discovered, that the negation bars from x_0 and x_1 are off. This means that the truth values inside makes no sense at all.

**How can I move the negation bar from the x_0 at the left to the x_0 at the right?**

I have more or less no TikZ experience which is why i used a package for this.

The [package documentation](http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/karnaughmap/karnaughmap.pdf) states on page 36 in the todo-notes that there currently is no possibility to permute the karnaugh map via direct TikZ interaction.

My goal:

[image: manipulated image of TikZ KV Diagram]

<sub>done via image manipulation, red arrow shows what changed</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've adapted my answer in [Drawing Karnaugh's maps in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/drawing-karnaughs-maps-in-latex/140581#140581) to fit your needs.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

%Empty Karnaugh map 4x4
\newenvironment{Karnaugh}%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=0.8]

\matrix (mapa) [matrix of nodes,
           nodes in empty cells,
         column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
         row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
         every node/.style={draw, minimum size=8mm, outer sep=0pt},
         row 1/.style={every node/.style={draw=none, minimum size=8mm, outer sep=0pt}},
         column 1/.style={every node/.style={draw=none, minimum size=8mm, outer sep=0pt}},
        ampersand replacement=\&]
{
|[draw=none]| \&[2mm] |(c01)| \& |(c11)| \& |(c10)| \& |(c00)| \\[2mm]
|(r01)| \& |(3)|  \& |(7)|  \& |(6)|  \& |(2)|  \\
|(r11)| \& |(11)| \& |(15)| \& |(14)| \& |(10)| \\
|(r10)| \& |(9)|  \& |(13)| \& |(12)| \& |(8)|  \\
|(r00)| \& |(1)|  \& |(5)|  \& |(4)|  \& |(0)|  \\
};
\draw (3.north west) -- node [pos=0.7,above right,anchor=south west, inner sep=1pt] {$x_2x_0$} node [pos=0.7,below left,anchor=north east, inner sep=1pt] {$x_3x_1$} ++(135:1);

\draw ([xshift=1mm]c01.south west)--node[above] {$x_0$} ([xshift=-1mm]c11.south east);
\draw ([xshift=1mm]c10.south west)--node[above] {$\overline{x_0}$} ([xshift=-1mm]c00.south east);
\draw ([yshift=-1mm]r01.north east)--node[left] {$x_1$} ([yshift=1mm]r11.south east);
\draw ([yshift=-1mm]r10.north east)--node[left] {$\overline{x_1}$} ([yshift=1mm]r00.south east);
\draw ([shift={(2mm,-1mm)}]2.north east)--node[right] {$\overline{x_3}$} ([shift={(2mm,1mm)}]2.south east);
\draw ([shift={(2mm,-1mm)}]10.north east)--node[right] {$x_3$} ([shift={(2mm,1mm)}]8.south east);
\draw ([shift={(2mm,-1mm)}]0.north east)--node[right] {$\overline{x_3}$} ([shift={(2mm,1mm)}]0.south east);
\draw ([shift={(1mm,-2mm)}]1.south west)--node[below] {$\overline{x_2}$} ([shift={(-1mm,-2mm)}]1.south east);
\draw ([shift={(1mm,-2mm)}]5.south west)--node[below] {$x_2$} ([shift={(-1mm,-2mm)}]4.south east);
\draw ([shift={(1mm,-2mm)}]0.south west)--node[below] {$\overline{x_2}$} ([shift={(-1mm,-2mm)}]0.south east);

}%
{
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%Defines 8 or 16 values (0,1,X)
\newcommand{\contingut}[1]{%
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 0]  in {#1}
     \path (\xi) node {\x};
}

%color fields
%#1 - comma separated list of filling terms. 
%#2 - filling color
\newcommand{\colorfields}[2]{%
\foreach \i in {#1}
   \fill[#2, opacity=.3] (\i.north west) rectangle (\i.south east);
}

%Places 1 in listed positions
\newcommand{\minterms}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {1};
}

%Places 0 in listed positions
\newcommand{\maxterms}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {0};
}

%Places X in listed positions
\newcommand{\indeterminats}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {X};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{Karnaugh}
\minterms{0,1,2,3}
\colorfields{0,1,2,3}{red}
\end{Karnaugh}
\end{document}
```

[image]