# How can I draw a 5 variable K Map with Karnaugh-Map package

Tags: karnaugh

I would like to draw a K map with 8 x-cells and 4 y-cells. Something like this:

```
\begin{karnaugh-map}[8][4][1][$Q_2$$Q_3$][$Q_0$$Q_1$]
    \terms{2,3}{X}
    \minterms{1,4,5,6,7}
\end{karnaugh-map}
```

But I cannot set that into the [] after the "\begin{karnaugh-map}" because the compiler crashes (Overleaf).

How do you do that without creating submaps?

Comment: Please show a minimal example code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440405/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87690/how-can-i-draw-a-karnaugh-map?rq=1

Comment: Or have a look at the `kvmap` package.