# Drawing Karnaugh Diagram

Tags: tables, karnaugh

How do I draw this table?  I am not able to place the variables outside the box. Also the the vertical borders are not of same length. So how do I vary the lengths of those vertical lines?
[image]
Secondly is there any simpler code to draw Karnaugh diagrams for 2x2 to 4x4 tables? [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/drawing-karnaughs-maps-in-latex) this was described but I find this quite complicated to understand and run. In particular, [image: this picture]. No need of coloured text.

Comment: There's also https://ctan.org/pkg/kvmap

Comment: Since the picture you provided seems not to be a kvmap, you can draw it using `matrix of nodes`. Do you want to insert values in the boxes later? Please, feel free to be more specific about the final purpose of this.

Comment: @SebGlav I've edited my question

Comment: Please add a sketch of what you need, in order to explain what you mean by *vary the lengths of those vertical lines*.

Comment: @SebGlav a 4 block k-diagram. then 8-block and 16-block k-diagram.

Answer (score 1):

One solution with `matrix of math nodes`.
[image: matrix of nodes]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex}]
            {
             & b_1 & b'_1 & \\
             &    &     & b'_3 \\
             &    &     &  \\
             &    &     &  \\
             &    &     & b'_3 \\            
            };
        \draw (m-1-1.south east) rectangle (m-5-3.south east);
        \draw (m-1-2.north east) -- (m-5-2.south east);
        \draw (m-2-1.south east) node[left=2.5mm] {$b_2$} -- (m-2-4.south east);
        \draw (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-3-4.south west) node[right=2.5mm] {$b_3$};
        \draw (m-4-1.south east) node[left=2.5mm] {$b'_2$} -- (m-4-4.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I think you may check the `NiceTabular` package with which you could create some very `nicematrix` in a nutshell.

Comment: with `tikz` package, I a receiving the error that `xstring.sty` is not found.

Comment: can you plz help me with the table drawing by pointing the directions. I have no idea about `south east` commands.

Comment: When creating a matrix of nodes like this one, you create a table with 5 rows and 4 columns, named `(m)`. Each cell (node) of this matrix is known by `(m-row-col)`, i.e. `(m-2-3)` means the cell at the 2nd row and the 3rd column. Each cell is a node, so you can call their many anchors (north, south, east, west, etc.) If you want to draw a line above a row, you draw from the above left corner of the first cell to the above right corner of the last one. Hence the `(m-5-2.north east)`naming. Hope this is clear.